unable to Internet from my ubuntu server through my comcast router
I recently purchased a ubuntu server and need it to connect to the internet through my comcast internet provider.  My comcast router shows up in the ubuntu wifi list; however, when I try and connect {after providing my comcast router password} it says connecting and then after a minute or so it asks for the password again. At one point it showed a check indicating that it was connected however it disappeared and went back to connecting.  When I try and use a browser {ex: safari} it is unable to reach the internet.

Have you tried connecting it over ethernet?

Look at the network logs with the terminal command: sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager.  Also do: service NetworkManager status. Please [edit] your question to add whatever new information you have. Do not use Add Comment.

You are using Safari on Ubuntu server...?

@vidarlo and it has wifi too. It's like no server I know...
